# Fedora 20 KDE: shortcut for airplane mode

Tags: wifi, kde, keyboard-shortcuts, networkmanager

is there a possiblity to have a Keyboard shortcut (e. g. fn + f10) for the airplane mode (Switch off all wifi Connections) under KDE (Fedora 20)?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/369646/create-a-shortcut-key-to-toggle-airplane-mode-on-off

Comment: Hmmm, actually, I think the answer is not what you want. What is Airplane Mode exactly? Is that a plasmoid?

Comment: Hi Sparhawk! Airplane Mode is the mode of KNetworkManager in which all wifi connections (WLAN) are switched off so that you can use your notebook in an airplane. My notebook offers a key with an airplane icon but it is without function, so I would like to put a shortcut on it. The link to Ubuntu is ok. The nmcli command works also with Fedora and it switches off all wifi connections, so technically it does the trick. But - and now comes the difficult part - in the GUI of the KNetworkManager the airplane icon is NOT ticked. I would like it to be ticked!!!

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now. I had a look thought the shortcuts in system settings (I guess you already did that), and found nothing. If you get nothing useful here, you can always ask at the kde forums, where they are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your bluetooth or wwan module is on, just turning the wifi off won't set the airplane mode. So you have to turn them off as well and then the GUI of the Networkmanager will show you that the airplane mode is on.

Comment: Hi Fabian, thanks a lot; but how do I turn off the bluetooth/wwan module??